# len(browser.find_elements_by_class_name('foo')) gives 0

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using python 3.7 and have got an error in selenium

I have a website looking something like that:

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="foo">
            <div class="bar1">something clickable</div>
            <div class="bar2">something clickable</div>
            <div class="bar3">something clickable</div>
            <div class="bar4">something clickable</div>
    </div>
<body>
<html>
```

and I want to use selenium to click each of the bars, so I wrote:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
browser=webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://www.some-website.com')
for i in browser.find_elements_by_class_name('foo'):
    i.click()
```

but, when executing I get nothing, so I run:

```py
print(len(browser.find_elements_by_class_name('foo')))
```

which outputs zero

even when I put `WebDriverWait` before I still get zero...

why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this xpath this will return 4 webelements

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='foo']//*")
```